# Why does Spark Planner prefer sort merge join over shuffled hash join?

Tags: apache-spark, join, apache-spark-sql

Why does Spark Planner in Spark 2.3 prefer a sort merge join over a shuffled hash join? In other words, why is `spark.sql.join.preferSortMergeJoin` configuration property [internal and turned on by default](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/sql/catalyst/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/internal/SQLConf.scala?utf8=%E2%9C%93#L157-L161)? What's wrong with a shuffled hash join? Is this specific to Spark that it does computations in distributed fashion or something else more inherent in the join algorithm?

You can find the property used in the `JoinSelection` execution planning strategy [here](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/execution/SparkStrategies.scala?utf8=%E2%9C%93#L259) and [here](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/execution/SparkStrategies.scala?utf8=%E2%9C%93#L266) that looks like:

```
case ... if !conf.preferSortMergeJoin && ... =>
  Seq(joins.ShuffledHashJoinExec(...))
```

Comment: Not a developer, haven't analyzed the implementation, but sorting is much simpler to offload from the memory. While theoretical slightly complexity is higher compared to creating hashing structure, getting next row from sorted structures is always O(1), and you get away with a single file descriptor if you really want to push data to disk. Not something you can do if you go with hashing.

Comment: And if I recall correctly Spark done a similar thing with RDD shuffle back in early or so, by switching from hash based to sort based shuffles.

Comment: Why this is voted as "primarily opinion based"? Question is not "which it's better", but "why it was choosen", as you can see there is a good and not primarily opinion based answer

Answer (score 25, accepted):

In order to answer your question

> What's wrong with a shuffled hash join?

I'll provide some context first.

---

According to [SPARK-11675](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-11675) Shuffled Hash Join was removed in Spark 1.6 and the reason was

> ... I think we should just standardize on sort merge join for large joins for now, and create better implementations of hash joins if needed in the future

and reintroduced in Spark 2.0 according to [SPARK-13977](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-13977) because

> ShuffledHashJoin is still useful when:
>
> 1) any partition of the build side could fit in memory
>
> 2) the build side is much smaller than stream side, the building hash table on smaller side should be faster than sorting the bigger side.

It's worth mentioning the [PR](https://github.com/apache/spark/pull/11788) for SPARK-13977 which points that Shuffled Hash Join was removed in favor of Sort Merge Join which is **faster** and **more robust**.

---

I'm not sure how much faster is *Sort Merge Join* compared to *Shuffled Hash Join* but it's definetelly more robust as Shuffled Hash Join requires the hashed table to fit in memory, counter to Sort Merge Join which can spill to disk.

Comment: Answer is fine, there should be a question to Spark developers - why then config is internal? @JacekLaskowski, maybe PR to make it non-internal?

Comment: I'll follow up on this in the dev mailing list to seek more info. Thanks for your help @T.Gawęda!

Comment: @JacekLaskowski can u pls provide the link to mail to spark user list..

Comment: @TahaKashaf I did not happen. Sorry.

Comment: @JacekLaskowski I am assuming shuffle hash join is better when one of the partition involved in the join is smaller and could fit in the memory otherwise merge sort join is preferred. if that is the case is it not possible to choose shuffle hash join or sort merge join dynamically for each partition in a table?. lets say we join two tables and for brevity the join shuffle creates 2 partitions for each relation. is it possible to choose shuffle hash join for partition #1 which is smaller in size and sort merge join for partition #2 since it is larger ..

Comment: @rogue-one It does not work this way. Only one type of join is used for all the partitions. It happens with or without CBO at planning time (based on the size of sides not partitions). I'd ask a separate question on SO to keep that question for others to learn from. Just saying... :)